# How to make the data (JSON) from the POST request automatically fall into the variable?

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to make a WinForm application with a web server.
Did so:
1. I use github.com - "eske / SimpleHttpServer" - link
 (https://github.com/jeske/SimpleHttpServer).
2. Created a WinForm project.
3. Added a link to the library project SimpleHttpServer
.. \ SimpleHttpServer \ bin \ Debug \ SimpleHttpServer.dll
4. Added code to Form1. (see below "My Code").

**Questions**
1. Have I correctly connected the server and WinForm?
2. How to make the data (JSON) that is transmitted in a POST request to my server automatically fall into the variable I need in WinForm?

**In other words:** as soon as the POST request arrives at the server, the data is  automatically placed in the variable.
 
 My goal: to get acquainted with the principles of work `Viber Api`.
For this, I propose to host the application on the local computer.
 WinWorm (user interface), which will interact with the server `Viber Api`). 
 Everything is placed on one computer and used by one user.
With the help of `Ngrok` application will be open to the Internet.
The `Ngrok` service provides links for`http: // localhost: XXXXX` links like `https: // 6eb5a091.ngrok.io /`
 
 
**My code.**

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            StartHttpServer();
}


static void StartHttpServer()
        {
            try
            {           

                // var route_config = new List<Models.Route>()
                var route_config = new List<Route>()
                {
                    new Route
                    {
                        Name = "Привет обработчик (Hello Handler)",
                        UrlRegex = @"^/$",
                        Method = "GET",

                        Callable = (HttpRequest request) =>
                        {
                            return new HttpResponse()
                            {
                                ContentAsUTF8 = "Привет от простого сервера Http (Hello from SimpleHttpServer)",
                                ReasonPhrase = "OK",
                                StatusCode = "200"
                            };
                        }
                    }, 
                    //new Route {   
                    //    Name = "FileSystem Static Handler",
                    //    UrlRegex = @"^/Static/(.*)$",
                    //    Method = "GET",
                    //    Callable = new FileSystemRouteHandler() { BasePath = @"C:\Tmp", ShowDirectories=true }.Handle,
                    //},
                };

                    HttpServer httpServer = new HttpServer(8080, route_config);

                    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(httpServer.Listen));
                    thread.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string s = ex.Message;
                string t = ex.StackTrace;
                // throw;
                MessageBox.Show(s + " \r\n "
                                  + t);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Side note: do you need UI and HTTPS to be in the same process? It would be far easier to get help (or rather read extensive documentations and how-to's) if you go with  asp.net/webAPI... Even if you have to host HTTP server inside your app going with more mainstream frameworks would make getting help easier... The project you've used had last commit 3 years ago - getting help may take some time (especially since you did not emphasize usage of rare package in title/tags)

Comment: **1.** `do you need UI and HTTPS to be in the same process?`  Is it difficult to implement?
The simpler the better for me.
**2.** And if in different processes, then these are two independent applications that need to be additionally connected to each other?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Forgot to address the last comment to you.

Comment: Clearly you've already implemented WinForms + HTTP - so that's seem to be easy enough... :) My suggestion is mostly to review what frameworks you already know / other people use and use them instead (i.e. https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20host%20owin%20winform may give you some ideas) rather than try to find the simplest code possible.